# Continuity and Differentiability Question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $F$ is monotone, continuous, and differentiable at all but countably many points. For all $x$ such that $F$ is differentiable at $x$, $F'(x) = 1/a$. Prove $F(x) = x/a + C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in each open interval $I_i$ where the function is differentiable, $F(x)=x/a+C_i$. Easy case: what happens between two contiguous intervals? (isolated point of nondifferentiablility) Harder case: what happens in a point of nondifferentiablility that is limit point of points of nondifferentiablility?

Comment: The case of isolated points is obvious.  I'm after the more general case (i.e., your "harder" part).  Do you have a more substantial hint for that?

Comment: Let be $x_0$ the point and $\epsilon>0$. Take  $I_i\cap(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)\ne\emptyset$, $I_j\cap(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)\ne\emptyset$, $C_i\ne C_j$.

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete solution?  I'm trying to use this fact but can't seem to prove it and your hints are less than helpful.

Comment: @asdf1234, is much easier: consider F(x)-x/a.